# addSublayer not displaying image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, calayer

I'm having trouble getting an image in a CAlayer to display in an imageView. I can get it to work with a CAGradientLayer, but as soon as I change it to a CALayer with an image, nothing seems to work. It doesn't even display part of the image as I would expect it to, if the frame was shifted.

I've made sure the image name is correct and exists. For background: testImageView is the only imageView and covers the entire screen.

```
let strokeLayer = CALayer()
strokeLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "test.png")
strokeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: testImageView.frame.width, height: testImageView.frame.height)
testImageView.layer.addSublayer(strokeLayer)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not set `textImageView.image = UIImage(named: "test.png")` ? Why use a layer to set an image for an image view?

Comment: Just trying to learn how to use a layer. Figured out I was just missing .cgImage at the end of the second line

Answer (score 1):

Figured out I was just missing .cgImage at the end of the second line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a image in CALayer you have to pass as

```
CGImage.strokeLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "test.png")?.cgImage
```